# Optimization from Reference Matrix

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, optimization

Have not found anything on this yet, any answers are appreciated. I apologize if this is the wrong place I am new to this.

I would like to minimize the sum of column B:

```
 A B
|1 0|
|2 #|
|3 #|
|4 #|
|5 #|
```

Column A row 1 will always be "1", while rows 2-5 can be moved around in order to minimize the sum. It's important to note that numbers 2-5 must all be used without repeating.

Column B gets its value by referencing the value of the number to the left and up 1 for the row, and the value of the number to the left for the column. The reference matrix looks like the following:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1|0 # # # # # # # #|
2|# 0 # # # # # # #|
3|# # 0 # # # # # #|
4|# # # 0 # # # # #|
5|# # # # 0 # # # #|
6|# # # # # 0 # # #|
7|# # # # # # 0 # #|
8|# # # # # # # 0 #|
9|# # # # # # # # 0|
```

For example, the second row of column B would use row 1, column 2 of the reference matrix, the third row of column B would use row 2, column 3 of the reference matrix, and so on.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Excel's `SMALL` function. To get the 4 smallest numbers in the diagonal above the main use a formulas like:

```
=SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),1)
=SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),2)
=SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),3)
=SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),4)
```

This assumes that the upper left element of the **reference matrix** is in A1, so the main diagonal is `A1,B2,C3,...`. Then the elements just above the main diagonal are `B1,C2,D3,...`.

The 1st argument to `SMALL` is an array of values, e.g. (B1,C2,D3,...). The 2nd argument is which value you want to extract: 1: smallest; 2: second smallest; etc. See the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/small-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07) for more details.

If you put the above formulas in cells H1:H4 of an excel sheet, then you could calculate their sum with `SUM(H1:H4)`.

You could also get the sum in a single, more complex formula like:

```
=SUM(SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),1),SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),2),SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),3),SMALL((B1,C2,D3,...),4))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Can you explain this more? From my understanding the small function would give me the smallest value from the row. I want to change the "2-5" values so that they will yield the smallest sum.

Comment: @MyCoolTomIs I added more explanation to the answer. Hope that gets you started